# TINYmce change fonts family trouble in Safari and MAC

Tags: fonts, tinymce

When i trying to change text fonts-family by TINYmce in Safary or MAC, the font-family becomes to `mceinline`, no matter which font i chose. But in all other browsers all works good.

Any body know how to resolve such problem?

Comment: how did you try to change the font-family by tinymce?

Comment: thay are in drop down font menu. Select text, than change the font

Comment: sry, i thought you would change it by content_css setting